# Jquery add Class and use as selector?

Tags: jquery, html, selector, addclass, removeclass

Hey so I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong with this,

Basically I have a button 'a#mobile_menu_btn' which I am adding a class to, '.active' which I then want to use as a selector, but it won't work.

```js
 $('a#mobile_menu_btn').click(function () { 
        $('a#mobile_menu_btn').addClass('active');
        $('#mobile_nav').addClass('expand');
    });

 $('a#mobile_menu_btn.active').click(function () { 
         $('#mobile_nav').addClass('expand');
         $('a#mobile_menu_btn').removeClass('active');
        
    });
```

I am unable to use toggle, as the button performs other functions so I wanted to keep it simple and just use Add / Remove class as when appropriate.

I've tried every variety of writing '$('a#mobile_menu_btn'); 
including ;

```js
$('a#mobile_menu_btn.active')
$('a#mobile_menu_btn .active')
$('span#mobile_menu_btn.active')
$('div#mobile_menu_btn.active')
$('a#mobile_menu_btn.active')
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need to use a class selector when you already have an id?

Comment: Notice that when you're setting `$('a#mobile_menu_btn.active').click(` , the button is not yet active. It doesn't have the `.active` class (it will get it when it's clicked). So this instruction doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's a really good example of how not to handle toggle functionality in jQuery, and what you should be doing is just keep the first event handler and toggle the classes with `toggleClass`, that's why it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As you are adding class dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

General Syntax

```
$(document).on(event, selector, eventHandler);
```

Ideally you should replace `document` with closest static container for better performance.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#mobile_menu_btn.active', function () { 
     $('#mobile_nav').addClass('expand');
     $('a#mobile_menu_btn').removeClass('active');
});
```

---

However You don't need event delegation as you can achieve same thing using [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$('a#mobile_menu_btn').click(function () { 
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Extra explanation: `$('a#mobile_menu_btn.active').click()` will bind the click event on all `a#mobile_menu_btn.active` elements which are **currently** in the document. This means that if you add the class later (with jQuery), the click event will not be bound to this new element. With `.on()` it binds the event on all current elements **and future** elements which are added later.